# Check if authentication info are correct with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making an app that needs to log in to a website.
The response that I get after sending a request to the website is 200, and I think that means that the request has been successful.
How can I make sure my login info are correct, in other words how can I know if I got logged in to the website.
I tried to log in with false login info and it sends 200 response.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://httpbin.org/#/Auth/get_basic_auth__user___passwd_)

Comment: But I also tried with wrong login info and it sends a response of 200

Comment: I would take a look at the response body that comes back, either with `r.json()` or `r.text` or something similar. There may be an indication there

Comment: @Funris Can you share URL of target web-site?

Comment: Maybe you can access some urls, which require login.

Comment: I was watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRSJSKG4mDA
I just want to know whether the login was successful of not.